# How to make that I do not need to type in x in inherrited classes>

Tags: c++

Basically this program calculates value in three different functions (kx+b, sin(x) and x^n) and is based on virtual methods. I need to type in x, k and b values, but the problem is, it asks me to type x three times. How do I make that x stays same and I don't need to write it again in other classes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Funckija
{
protected:
    double x;
public:
    Funckija();
    virtual double calculation()=0;
};

Funckija::Funckija()
{
    cout<<"Type in x ";
    cin>>x;
}
class Tiesine: public Funckija
{
private:
    int k;
    int b;
public:
    Tiesine();
double calculation();
};

Tiesine::Tiesine()
{
    cout<<"Type in k and b "<<endl;
    cin>>k>>b;
}
double Tiesine::calculation()
{
    return k*x+b;
}

class Sinusoidine: public Funckija
{
public:
double calculation();
};

double Sinusoidine::calculation()
{
    return sin(x);
}

class Rodykline: public Funckija
{
private:
    int n;
public:
    Rodykline();
    double calculation();
};

Rodykline::Rodykline()
{
    cout<<"Type in n ";
    cin>>n;
}
double Rodykline::calculation()
{
    return pow(x, n);
}
int main()
{
Funckija *N[3];
N[0]= new Tiesine;
N[1]= new Sinusoidine;
N[2]= new Rodykline;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout<<N[i]->calculation()<<endl;
}
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry, code isn't completely english.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking. You have 3 objects, all of which have separate `x` values. Do you perhaps want to make `x` a `static` member?

Comment: `cout<<"Type in x "; cin>>x;` - do this once and don't put it in the class?

Comment: Yes, I want to make that all 3 objects have same x value.

Comment: Do your std::cin in your main function. Don't do it in the classes.

Comment: If I understand the question, the presentation might be clearer if you added the actual and desired output, including the prompts for input. (I would put these above the code and below the existing problem description.)